# Batch string `replace`?

Tags: python, replace, str-replace, batch-processing, batch-rename

Using system libraries, this would be very inefficient:

```
foo = "foo bar car haz can bar foo"
repl = {('foo', 'bar'), ('car', 'bar'), ('foo', 'haz')}

for rep in repl:
    foo = foo.replace(rep)
```

A replacement batch `replace` should solve this problem in O(|foo| + |repl|) rather than O(|foo| × |repl|) as in the above approach.

Can you think of a concise way of implementing this more efficient solution?

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Comment: Syntactic error in your code: In the last line you need to unpack arguments: `foo = foo.replace(*rep)`

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions

```
import re

foo = "foo bar car haz can bar foo"

re.sub(r"(foo|car)", "bar", foo)

> 'bar bar bar haz can bar bar'
```

Actually it is slower with in this case:

```
import timeit

timeit.timeit('re.sub(r"(foo|car)", "bar", "foo bar car haz can bar foo")', 'import re', number=10000)

> 0.051492929458618164

def test():
    foo = "foo bar car haz can bar foo"
    repl = [('foo', 'bar'), ('car', 'bar'), ('foo', 'haz')]
    for rep in repl:
        foo = foo.replace(*rep)

timeit.timeit("test()", setup="from __main__ import test", number=10000)

> 0.026629924774169922
```

Comment: I haven't analysed regex much, what is the complexity of that operation?

Comment: Additionally I have edited the question by adding `('foo', 'haz')` to the `repl` set.

Comment: I don't understand the modification: which "foo"s do you want to be replaced by "haz" if any? Or is this more a theoretical runtime consideration?